# Wagtail Filter ForeignKey By Current User

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am trying to build a progress tracker for an educational training app in Wagtail. I use a PageModel to represent a "Lesson":

```py
# courses/models.py

class SectionLessonPage(Page):
    lesson_video = models.ForeignKey('wagtailvideos.Video',
                                     related_name='+',
                                     null=True,
                                     on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        VideoChooserPanel('lesson_video'),
    ]

    def serve(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            lesson_viewed_signal.send(self.__class__, instance=self, request=request)
            return super().serve(request)
```

And I have a separate 'progress' app, which receives a signal from the serve function to record a page visit by a specific user.

```py
# progress/models.py

class UserLessonView(models.Model):
    lesson = models.ForeignKey(
        'courses.SectionLessonPage',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="views"
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    viewed_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

This establishes a one-to-many relationship between the two models. However, the current logged in user is not taken into account when in the template I try to obtain the SectionLessonPage's 'views' for the logged in user.

Since the current user is not a field of SectionLessonPage, there is no model relationship to use. Instead possibly this needs to be handled in the get_context() or serve() method of SectionLessonPage.

The problem is that the when I call {{ self.views }} on the SectionLessPage template, it returns all views for all users.
I need it to return the views only for the current user. How can I pass the views for this page, filtered for the current user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.views.filter(user=request.user)` would do it. You can't call `filter` within the template itself (because the Django template language doesn't provide a way to pass parameters to functions), but you can do this [within the page's `get_context` method](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/getting_started/tutorial.html#overriding-context) to make that result available as a variable in the template:

```
class SectionLessonPage(Page):
    # ...
    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        context['user_views'] = self.views.filter(user=request.user)
        return context
```

This result will then be available in the template as `{{ user_views }}`.

Comment: Thanks Matt, this makes a lot of sense!

Comment: One more question: this would only work when being called in SectionLessonPage's own template, right? I.e. if in the template of SectionLessonPage's parent, i would call {{ self.get_children.first.user_views }} - that would not work right, since request is not being passed on the get_children function?

Comment: Yes, that wouldn't work, because we haven't defined a 'user_views' method on SectionLessonPage - we've only made it available as a variable at the point of rendering SectionLessonPage's own template. Again, rather than trying to put this logic inside the template you'd be better off putting that query in a `get_context` method on the parent page model.